# how do i test Exactly Once Semantics working in my kafka streams application

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

i have a Kafka Streams DSL application, we have a requirement on exactly once processing, for the same i have added the configuration

```
streamConfig.put(processing.gurantee, "exactly_once");
```

I am using kafka 2.7
I have 2 queries

1. what's the difference between exactly_once and exactly_once_beta
2. how do i test this functionality to be sure my messages are getting processed only once

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`exactly_once_beta` is an improvement over `exactly_once`. While `exactly_once` uses a transactional producer for each stream task (combination of sub-topology and input partition, `exactly_once_beta` uses a transactional producer for each stream thread of a Kafka Streams client.
Every producer comes with separate memory buffers, a separate thread, separate network connections which might limit scaling the number of input partitions (i.e. number of tasks). A high number of producers might also cause more load on the brokers. Hence, `exactly_once_beta` has better scaling characteristics. You can find more details in [KIP-447](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-447%3A+Producer+scalability+for+exactly+once+semantics).

Note that `exactly_once` will be deprecated and `exactly_once_beta` will be renamed to `exactly_once_v2` in Apache Kafka 3.0. See [KIP-732](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-732%3A+Deprecate+eos-alpha+and+replace+eos-beta+with+eos-v2) for more details.

For tests you can get inspiration from the tests in the Apache Kafka repo:

- https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/streams/src/test/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/integration/EosIntegrationTest.java
- https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/streams/src/test/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/integration/EOSUncleanShutdownIntegrationTest.java
- https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/tests/kafkatest/tests/streams/streams_eos_test.py

Basically, you need to create a failover scenario and verify that messages are not produced multiple times to the output topics. Note that messages may be processed multiple times, but the results in the output topics must appear as if they were only processed once. You can find a pretty good talk about exactly-once semantics that also explains the failover scenarios here: https://www.confluent.io/kafka-summit-london18/dont-repeat-yourself-introducing-exactly-once-semantics-in-apache-kafka/